# Error in Indexes and very Slow in all Queries

Tags: php, mysql, performance

this table have all problems in the world :(
slow in search with fields name_ar , name_en with Query LIKE , 
slow with SELECT query with fields cid , uid , sid , ssid , product_id , havproduct
very slow in INSERT Query 
i think that Error in the indexes in this table

**table create**

```
CREATE TABLE `eng_subjects` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `did` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ssid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `havproduct` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `shortcut` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ar_name` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `en_name` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ar_desc` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `en_desc` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ar_pic` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `en_pic` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `video` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `piclinknews` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `active_links` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stop_smile` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscribe` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscribe_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `close` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `orderBy` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `viewnum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `updated` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pin_from` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pin_to` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `up_to` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted_reason` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'not Deleted',
  `average_price` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_update` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `discomment` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `dep_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `subject_idx_did` (`did`),
  KEY `idx_uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `idx_cid` (`cid`),
  KEY `idx_pin2` (`sid`,`deleted`,`pin_to`,`close`),
  KEY `engine4_subject_date` (`date`),
  KEY `idx_cid2` (`cid`,`deleted`,`close`),
  KEY `engine4_subject1` (`product_id`,`deleted`),
  KEY `idx_prodid1` (`product_id`,`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22383826 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**query Insert**

```
INSERT INTO eng_subjects (`ar_name`,`en_name`,`video`,`piclinknews`,`ar_desc`,`en_desc`,`country_id`,`active_links`,`stop_smile`,`subscribe`,`subscribe_type`,`shortcut`,`cid`,`did`,`sid`,`ssid`,`orderBy`,`discomment`,`uid`) 
VALUES ('test title','test title','','','testing content','testing content','62','','','','','','24','26','437','0','2014-07-26 11:08:40','0','1165262')
```

result insert
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEyPB.png

**Query select**

```
select * from `eng_subjects` WHERE `cid` = 24 and active = 1 and `deleted` = 0 order by id desc LIMIT 30
```

**Explain**

```
id  select_type table       type    possible_keys       key     key_len ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE      eng_subjects ref    idx_cid,idx_cid2    idx_cid 4       const   205438  Using where
```

this table have update in fields `views` every visit this subject
i think that copy structure and create new table with same name 
and move all data to new table and remove all Indexes in the Old Table
 but what's the best way to add Indexes in this table .

---

I think that the problem of additive and very slow because of the large number of indexes bad things .. what about remove all Indexes ?

> `Table    Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name     Collation   Cardinality     Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment     Index_comment
>   eng_subjects        0   PRIMARY     1   id  A   196089  NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   subject_idx_did     1   did     A   3   NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   idx_uid     1   uid     A   49022   NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   idx_pin2    1   sid     A   139     NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   idx_pin2    2   deleted     A   338     NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   idx_pin2    3   pin_to  A   1203    NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   idx_pin2    4   close   A   1474    NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   engine4_subject_date    1   date    A   196089  NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   engine4_subject1    1   product_id  A   4   NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   engine4_subject1    2   deleted     A   4   NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   idx_prodid1     1   product_id  A   4   NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   idx_prodid1     2   deleted     A   4   NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   idx_for_qry     1   cid     A   100     NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   idx_for_qry     2   active  A   100     NULL    NULL        BTREE
>
>   eng_subjects        1   idx_for_qry     3   deleted     A   100     NULL    NULL        BTREE`

Comment: What indexes you need depends on the queries you run on this table. There is no generic answer to this question. How bis is this table currently? The `INSERT` is really incredibly slow...

Comment: Are your indexes fully analyzed and up to date? Very old indexes can give these kinds of results.

Comment: I wanted to sound sarcastic at first, but I'll just be polite - these things run on hardware, it might be the case that you're experiencing a fault with your hard disk or that the whole system is under load. Also, you didn't tell us whether you optimized MySQL  so that InnoDB can utilize available RAM or not.

Comment: These fields are used takes place on a continuous basis in the call ,checks and search
 id,
cid,
sid,
ssid,
product_id,
havproduct,
uid,
ar_name,
en_name,
close,
active,
date,
orderBy,
pin_to,
up_to,
deleted,
country_id,
user_active,
dep_active

Comment: As far as I know, the "VARCHAR" has a max-length of 255 characters and you're using "VARCHAR(500)". Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html
I know it isn't an answer for your problem, but first of all, you need to have a valid MySQL code.

Comment: It's better to READ ("select" etc.) from one database and to WRITE ("insert", "update", "delete" etc.) from another database. This process is called Master and Slave (Replication). Writing data to the database takes a lot of time, that's why you need to use this process. Read more: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8680/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-mysql-master-slave-replication-setup-and-troubles
This can be easily done on any decent Database Cloud Hosting solutions (Amazon RDS etc.)

Comment: thanks for all but problem in same table.. 
I have used optimize and repair table MySQL
indexes have written the wrong way and the bad, which caused a severe slow when Use insert 
I can delete all the indexes, but what are the best ways to add alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with this key:

```
KEY `idx_for_qry` (`cid`,`active `,`deleted`)
```

**And remove 'idx_cid'** because if you have a composite key the first field of the key is just indexed

Comment: If the explain still shows it using an inappropriate index (idx_cid2 for instance) you might need to use an index hint (IE USE INDEX (idx_for_qry) - see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html